# Web api routing two controller similar action and parameter not populating parameter value in one action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two webapi controller ControllerA and ControllerB. Each has got one POST action i.e

### ControllerA

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Action1(CustomObjectA req, string pan="")
```

### ControllerB

```
 [HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage Action2(CustomObjectB req, string mpxn="")
```

My web api routing is as shown below

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "Purchase",
       routeTemplate: "{controller}/{pan}",
       defaults: new
           {
               controller  = "ControllerA"
               pan = RouteParameter.Optional
            });

  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "Vend",
      routeTemplate: "{controller}/{mpxn}",
      defaults: new
      {
           controller = "ControllerB",
           mpxn = RouteParameter.Optional
      });
```

When i invoke POST request from fiddler to /ControllerA/1 it works fine i.e value for pan parameter in Action1 is set to 1
but when i invoke POST request from fiddler to /ControllerB/2, it comes to Action2 but the value for mpxn is not set and it is "".
Can anyone please correc me the mistake i have done in routing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hope these links help to you: [attribute routing-1](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)    [attribute routing-2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing)

> Attribute routing gives you more control over the URIs in your web API. For example, you can easily create URIs that describe hierarchies of resources.
>
> The earlier style of routing, called convention-based routing, is still fully supported. In fact, you can combine both techniques in the same project.